How do I get fast path installed for my jd edwards admin account? i need to add a new user
I was given documentation to add a new user. It says type in 'users' in fast path then a screen to first search if the new user exists then to add. but I don't have fast path. how do I get it?

I don't think this question belongs here. I'm guessing you should be looking to JD Edwards documentation or support resources.
